# Does this washing machine drum look good?

Tags: leak, washing-machine

I'm trying to find the source of a bad leak on my washing machine. i have no experience with those.

I tuned it on it's side hopping that it would be a pump hose loose. as it leaks during rinsing, and letting water out by the '[bleeder hose](http://i100.photobucket.com/albums/m39/dz63/LG%20WH2477HW%20Washer%20Pump%20Repair/IMG_1721.jpg)'(?) causes less water to leak underneath... but by looking on the hoses going to the pump, nothing appears odd. all hoses appear new and clips are perfectly in place.

but i found two other things that may be the culprit. the seams on the drum, and a weird looking 'cement' on the front of the drum underside.

here is an overview picture.
(sorry can't attach the pictures here as they are too big and i can't edit right now. also i think bigger pics can help see the detail in this case)

[overview from underneath](http://www.googledrive.com/host/0B1khElyxxb_pYkotVHFxaHRWeVE/bottom.jpg)

for this picture, imagine the machine laid down on it's left. so the back is on the left of the image, and the front is on the right.

and here is a [zoom on the underside of the drum](https://6aa2cb96e3f727a362aa1a16b61b5fed8387effe-www.googledrive.com/host/0B1khElyxxb_pYkotVHFxaHRWeVE/drum.jpg)

Does that looks normal? is that just so that the seam is tight? or is the plastic giving away already?

the other thing that i found strange was the cement like rectangle on the right... [underneath drum, front.](http://www.googledrive.com/host/0B1khElyxxb_pYkotVHFxaHRWeVE/drumfront.jpg) you can see where it is on the overview pic on the right, where the yellow cable disappear.

this is under the recessed part where the front loading door seal goes in. it seems like there was a hole there, and it was sealed with epoxy or something.

does any of those things look bad?

Comment: those swelling seams definitely don't look 100%, but you could check if they are wet after a load, my gut says its a hose fitting or a dirty overflow. the cement filled thing looks normal, its either filled to act as a counter weight, or just to make the inside of the drum feel more solid.

Comment: when i finally managed to move it out of the tight space it was, and open it, it was already completely dry. now i'm debating running a test load knowing it will leak, or just replacing the pump (as all hose seems fine). it did have lots of sand on the filter and i cleaned. but still, no clue where the water came from... it is hard running a test load when the genius landlord made the laundry on the 2nd floor with carpet... sigh